# Calculating the basic algebra over a finite field in GAP

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, gap, group-rings

Assume $A$ is a (nonsemisimple) finite dimensional algebra over a finite field $K$ (for example a group algebra).
I want to calculate the basic algebra $B$ of $A$ as a matrix algebra, constructed as follows:

First possibility: Let $e=e_1+e_2+...+e_n$ be the sum of nonisomorphic primitive orthogonal idempotents such that every indecomposable projective modules is isomorphic to $e_iA$ for some $i$.
Then $B=eAe$.

Second possibility: Let $P_i, i=1,..,n$ be a list of all nonisomorphic indecomposable projective modules, then $B=End_A(P_1 \oplus P_2 ... \oplus P_n)$.

Is there a way GAP can do this?

Comment: Perhaps you need GAP meataxe - look at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/463222/. Do you have an example of a group algebra to work with?

Comment: maybe a symmetric group over a field of characteristic p diving the order of the group.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there is no turnkey implementation for GAP that computes the basic algebra. As far as algorithmic approaches go, the `meataxe`-methods are probably the way to g. In particular you might want to look at the commands `MTX.Indecomposition`, `MTX.HomogeneousComponents` and
`MTX.BasisModuleEndomorphisms`
in GAP. (However the current implementation for endomorphisms is much weaker than that for automorphisms.)
Also look at the C-meataxe and the endomorphism computations at:
http://math.arizona.edu/~klux/software.php